# Flutter app hosted on github shows blank screen

Tags: flutter, github, web-applications

github repo : https://github.com/joevarghese53/money_manager
site : https://joevarghese53.github.io/money_manager/
source code of flutter app : https://github.com/joevarghese53/moneymanager-flutterproject
I hosted a flutter web app on github and it is only showing a blank white screen . does anyone know the fix?

i am able to run it from visual studio using -d chrome and it runs properly but the github hosted page is showing a blank screen.